# Add sampler is missing in jmeter UI

Tags: jmeter

I am a jmeter rookie. All the tutorials I am seeing about jmeter talk about adding sampler to the jmx script. However, I don't see Add -> Sampler option in the jmeter UI. I have tried jmeter 5.6.2, jmeter 3.3 and jmeter 2.13.

[image]

I am running jmeter on mac os ventura (Apple M2 processor). Using openjdk 17.

Comment: Update: I was right clicking on the root test plan. Samplers can't be added to the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samplers cannot be added to the root test plan element. They must be added to a *thread group* container.  First, add a thread group to your test plan:

[image]

Then, you can add samplers as desired.  These will be contained within the thread group as child elements:

[image]

JMeter offers many types of [thread groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group).  Depending on what your intentions are for your load test, you may use any of the following thread groups to contain your samplers:

- *Thread Group (default)*
- *Stepping Thread Group*
- *Ultimate Thread Group*
- *Concurrency Thread Group*
- *Arrivals Thread Group*
- *Free-Form Arrivals Thread Group*
- *Open Model Thread Group*

For your specific use case, you will need to select the best thread group that matches your testing goals.  For simple proof-of-concept tests, the default thread group will usually suffice.  If you need to scale your test, or need to probe more complex scenarios, your test might benefit from an [advanced thread group](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2023/07/best-jmeter-thread-group/).

Answer (score 1):

First you need to add Thread Group of your choice under Test Plan(By choosing Add->Threads(Users)), then you can add Samplers to Thread Group.

Comment: Which jmeter version are you using? Which os?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) first, then the option for adding a [sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) will be available via context menu:

[image]

Also be aware that you can just record your test scenario using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium).